# Using glob in C++ to return files

Tags: c++, glob, file-search

I've been trying to play around with glob in C++ but have been having some issues... Essentially I am giving it a path and expecting to get the list of files back. Here is my code:

```
const string path = "/home/admin/filesDir/";
glob_t glob_r;
glob( (path + "*").c_str(), GLOB_NOSORT, NULL, &glob_r);
```

Now in the directory there are 3 files currently. Yet when I print out glob_r.gl_pathc it only says 1. And when I try to print that our it is blank. I am running this code from /home/admin but I would expect glob to return to me the number of files from the path I am giving it. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a chance that the version of glob on my system is broken.

(I am running on an older Unix box - looks like glob.h was last updated in 2001 on my system.)

Comment: Seems to be working for me in OSX 10.11.4. Are all three regular not hidden files? Because it doesn't list/count those...

Comment: yep. The file names are just foo.txt, foo_0.txt, and foo_1.txt. If its working for you I am going to assume its the version of my system...